# How to get input text value in ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get `input` text value and store it in a variable named `input` in `ionic`. But I tried and failed. Can anyone please tell me what I have faulty done?

This is my `HTML`

```
  <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item> 
        <ion-label stacked>display</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" text-right id="input" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>    
  </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

and this is my `home.ts` in ionic

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    var input=document.getElementById('input').nodeValue;
    document.getElementById('seven').innerHTML=input;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually you seems to be using angular not angularjs, use [(ngModel)]

```
 <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" text-right id="input" ></ion-input>
```

and inside the component,

**`name:string;`**

so whenever you need the value , you can use.

**`console.log(this.name);`**

Comment: I tried this. but is this `ng-model` works for newer versions too?

Comment: what do you mean by new versions?

Comment: and how do I get `ng-model` value to whenever I needed?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: **[ts]
Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'Component'.**

Comment: did you restart the application?

Comment: @user8794865 make sure you added above the constructor

Comment: No. Why I should restart it? Are you aware that I'm using this in the `ionic` framework? and I'm using `angularjs`.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I add it under `@Component`

Comment: add it inside the export above constructor

Comment: then this is the error I'm getting... **[ts] 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.**

Comment: What if I need to get element by ID as well, is there a way to ensure that we get the reference using `getElementByID`?

Answer (score 16):

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item> 
      <ion-label stacked>display</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" text-right id="input" [(ngModel)]="inputValue"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>    
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

// ===

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    inputValue: string = "";
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

    someFunction() {
        // here you can use the 'this.inputValue' and get the value of the ion-input 
    }

}
```

we use the two way binding the value of ion-input with the class member inputValue,

[about ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#how-to-use)

whan you need to access on the value of the input, check the value of inputValue.

**here you can see an exemple I wrote on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-c8g4un?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

> **Two-way binding** is a combination of both property binding and event binding as it is a continuous synchronization of data/values from presentation layer to component and from component to the presentation layer.
>
> Since this is a two way binding we have to use both the brackets - [ ( ) ]. Also ngModel is a directive which is used to bind the data both ways.

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 5 - The way to get the value of an ion-input value when focusing:

```
<ion-input (ionFocus)="onFocusPlace($event)"></ion-input>

onFocusPlace(event){
    this.value = event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please leave some description when you answer the questions, do not simply provide some code (e.g. why your code works, what was the problem of the OP code).